# Как сохранить ps в читабельный JSON?

Tags: json, powershell

Результат выполнения данных команд и одной функции хочу сохранить в json файл для дальнейшей загрузки на сервер. Как это сделать?

```
$Test = @"
{
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem |  Format-Table Domain, Name 
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BaseBoard | Format-Table Manufacturer, Product, SerialNumber
Get-WMIObject win32_Processor
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Manufacturer,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Devicelocator,Capacity,Serialnumber -autosize 
Get-Disk

Function ConvertTo-Char
(    
    $Array
)
{
    $Output = ""
    ForEach($char in $Array)
    {    $Output += [char]$char -join ""
    }
    return $Output
}

$Query = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * FROM WMIMonitorID" -Namespace root\wmi

$Results = ForEach ($Monitor in $Query)
{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ComputerName = $env:ComputerName
        Active = $Monitor.Active
        Manufacturer = ConvertTo-Char($Monitor.ManufacturerName)
        UserFriendlyName = ConvertTo-Char($Monitor.userfriendlyname)
        SerialNumber = ConvertTo-Char($Monitor.serialnumberid)
        WeekOfManufacture = $Monitor.WeekOfManufacture
        YearOfManufacture = $Monitor.WeekOfManufacture


    }


}

$Results | Select ComputerName,Active,Manufacturer,UserFriendlyName,SerialNumber,WeekOfManufacture,YearOfManufacturermation 
}
"@ | Out-File "C:\file3.json"
```

Comment: вы хоть поясните, что у вас получается, и что хотите получить? Вопрос то в слове _читабельный_ или вообще как сохранить в json, а то я тут конвертации никакой не вижу

Comment: За ранее извиняюсь за не понятную картину вопроса. У меня в файл сохраняется исходный код вместо нужного результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как то так
    gwmi -Query "Select * FROM WMIMonitorID" -Namespace root\wmi | select ComputerName, Active, Manufacturer, UserFriendlyName, SerialNumber, WeekOfManufacture, YearOfManufacturermation | ConvertTo-Json | sc "C:\file3.json"